# how to link a java class to a image button in eclipse?

Tags: java, android, image, imagebutton

I am trying to create a application that includes a Imagebutton and by clicking on the imagebutton, the application will start to run another java class that is within the package itself. I try using this method, however the program stopped working immediately? how should i code the codes instead? can anyone help me? Thanks :D

```
package com.fyp.gulliver;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class GulliverActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        //---Map button---
        Button btnMap = (Button) findViewById(R.id.map);
        btnMap.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        Class ourClass; 
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                try {
                    ourClass = Class.forName
                        ("com.fyp.gulliver.Maps");
                    Intent ourIntent = new Intent(GulliverActivity.this, ourClass);
                    startActivity(ourIntent);
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    } 
}
```

Comment: I try the codes the intent code however it is still showing the message forced to close when i try it on the emulator. the class Maps is also added to the manifest already. wonder what is wrong with it? thanks :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Button btnMap = (Button) findViewById(R.id.map);
        btnMap.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        Class ourClass; 
            public void onClick(View v) {

            Intent i = new Intent(GulliverActivity.this, Maps.Class);
            startActivity(i);

});
```

You need to create the object of the class u want to use!!(in case of non act class)

Answer (score 0):

Create intent like this

```
Intent ourIntent = new Intent(GulliverActivity.this, Maps.Class);
startActivity(ourIntent);
```

Comment: I have a doubt..Can we start a normal class(non activity and not even a receiver or a service) directly from an activity ?

Answer (score 0):

Your class ( ourClass) should be either an activity, service, receiver, provider, .... And you should record it in your manifest file to work.